# Integration of talend geospatial component

Tags: geospatial, talend

I'm new in Talend word. I'm using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration and I want to perform some operation with geospatial data.

I downloaded such component and I followed the step in the installation file:
copy the component of the plugin directory in the plugins directory of TOS, but I'm not able to visualize spatial components in the palette!

Could you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details. Are you having any errors ?

Comment: No errors. I don't see those component in the palette, even if I see the goemetry datatype within talend DI

Comment: Could you explain me this FAQ of the spatial plugin installation? "*After spatial plugins installation, no spatial components appears in the palette ?
Start from a clean TOS zip and do not start TOS before unzipping spatial plugins."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download a fresh copy of the Talend Open Data zip (http://talend.dreamhosters.com/tos/release/V5.3.0/TOS_DI-r101800-V5.3.0.zip)
2. Unzip the plugin into the plugins folder
3. Start Talend.

**Do not start talend before step 2 is complete.**

Comment: Ok thanks. One question: in order import all my work done I have just to replace the workspace from my old installation to the new one? THANKS

Comment: Use the import option you see when opening talend

Answer (score 0):

- Download TOS DI from http://www.talend.com

  - Unzip TOS DI
  - Download Spatial module http://sourceforge.net/projects/sdispatialetl/files/sdispatialetl/
  - Unzip Spatial module
  - Copy the content of the plugin directory in the plugins directory of TOS.
  - Start TOS

Regards